# How to serializer django-mysql's JSON field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django together with the django-mysql library to be able to make use of its JSON Field.

However I'm having a problem writing a serializer for my model. Here's the model:

***models.py***

```
from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model

class PhoneTest(Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

***views.py***

```
class PhoneTestView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = PhoneTestSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print('data is valid: {}'.format(serializer.data))
            print('saving to a db...')
            serializer.save()
        else:
            print('data is not valid: {}'.format(serializer.data))

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

***serializers.py***

```
class PhoneTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.JSONField(binary=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PhoneTest
        fields = ['data']
```

What is returned is an empty object `{}`. Certainly it's a problem with the serializer. I think I could indeed avoid using it at all and write something like:

```
PhoneTest.objects.create(data=request.data)
```

But I'm not sure if it's bon ton.

**EDIT**:

here is what the json I'm posting looks like:

```
{'mAutomaticTestCompleted': True, 'mAutomaticTestList': [{'mCountWifiNetworks': 17, 'mName': 'Wifi module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Bluetooth module', 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Battery module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mValue': -748}, {'mAvailableRamSize': 1036046336, 'mName': 'Memory module', 'mTestStatus': False, 'mTotalRamSize': 1949261824}, {'mAvailableStorageSize': 10391855104, 'mName': 'Internal storage module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mTotalStorageSize': 11810320384}, {'mAdvancedStatus': True, 'mAvailableEasy': 10391855104, 'mEasyStatusTest': True, 'mName': 'SD card module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mTotalEasy': 11810320384}, {'mGsmStatus': False, 'mName': 'GSM module', 'mSimStatus': False, 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Accelerator module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mX': 2.49, 'mY': 4.98, 'mZ': 10.34}, {'mName': 'Light Sensor module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mValue': 145}], 'mDeviceManufacturer': 'Vertex', 'mDeviceModelName': 'Impress_Phonic', 'mGlobalDeviceStatus': False, 'mImei': '097264011583257', 'mMac': '02:00:00:00:00:00', 'mManualTestList': [{'mName': 'Display module', 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Back Light module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Flashlight module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Headset or jack module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Receiver module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Speaker module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Vibration module', 'mTestStatus': True}], 'mOfficerCode': 'xian', 'mSemiautomaticTestList': [{'mName': 'QR code module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Buttons module', 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Microphone module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mCounter': 0, 'mName': 'Multitouch module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'GPS module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'PSensor module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Touchscreen module', 'mTestStatus': True}], 'mDate': '10/5/2018, 11:05:04 AM'}
```

Comment: `serializer.is_valid()` is a boolean and is usually something you do an `if` with to see if it is valid before saving... to me it looks like you are trying to circumvent all the safety built into DRF

Comment: @Incognos well no, the thing is that it's not a complete view, I do know what the `is_valid()` method is used for. However it has nothing to do with the problem I'm facing. At least I believe so.

Comment: why are you defining the validate method? the model will do the validation and return data if it is a valid JSON. Properly checking to see if the validation passed would be a first step with the if, then checking if the serializer is returning errors. defensive programming...

Comment: @Incognos Yeah the validate method is redundant here, I first did it to see what exactly goes into `value`. `serializer.is_valid()` returns `False` indeed and the `validate` method is not called at all. I can't say I understand why.

Comment: @Incognos I've introduced some changes into the code to make it look a little better, however I'm sort of debugging so, there is some rubbish here and there...

Comment: did you try printing out `request.data` to see if there is anything being submitted? is this a POST?

Comment: @Incognos Yes, sure, `request.data` gives me the json I'm posting. Yes, it's a POST.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182794/discussion-between-incognos-and-gobear).

Comment: @Incognos Oh perhaps I did not state it clear but that json field I'm using comes from the django-mysql library. I believe that's where the problem with serialization comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

`serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)`

is expecting json formatted as

`{'data': {'mAutomaticTestCompleted': True, 'mAutomaticTestList': [{'mCountWifiNetworks': 17, 'mName': 'Wifi module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Bluetooth module', 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Battery module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mValue': -748}, {'mAvailableRamSize': 1036046336, 'mName': 'Memory module', 'mTestStatus': False, 'mTotalRamSize': 1949261824}, {'mAvailableStorageSize': 10391855104, 'mName': 'Internal storage module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mTotalStorageSize': 11810320384}, {'mAdvancedStatus': True, 'mAvailableEasy': 10391855104, 'mEasyStatusTest': True, 'mName': 'SD card module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mTotalEasy': 11810320384}, {'mGsmStatus': False, 'mName': 'GSM module', 'mSimStatus': False, 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Accelerator module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mX': 2.49, 'mY': 4.98, 'mZ': 10.34}, {'mName': 'Light Sensor module', 'mTestStatus': True, 'mValue': 145}], 'mDeviceManufacturer': 'Vertex', 'mDeviceModelName': 'Impress_Phonic', 'mGlobalDeviceStatus': False, 'mImei': '097264011583257', 'mMac': '02:00:00:00:00:00', 'mManualTestList': [{'mName': 'Display module', 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Back Light module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Flashlight module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Headset or jack module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Receiver module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Speaker module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Vibration module', 'mTestStatus': True}], 'mOfficerCode': 'xian', 'mSemiautomaticTestList': [{'mName': 'QR code module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Buttons module', 'mTestStatus': False}, {'mName': 'Microphone module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mCounter': 0, 'mName': 'Multitouch module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'GPS module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'PSensor module', 'mTestStatus': True}, {'mName': 'Touchscreen module', 'mTestStatus': True}], 'mDate': '10/5/2018, 11:05:04 AM'}}`

**notice the `data` attribute - which is important in this case

which is why it is not picking up the contents of your post. modify your payload and it should pick it up properly.

Comment: Aaaaaahh, too right. I can see it now. Yeah, thank you ever so much!